# Consumir y recorrer api php

Tags: php, array

Estoy consumiendo la api con la información de una de unas ordenes, lo que quiero es acceder a los id de cada una.

```
    $headers = [
        "clientAutCookie:ffff"
    ];

    $ch = curl_init("url");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($response,true);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";

    /*var_dump($data);*/

    foreach ($data as $repository){
        echo $repository["orderId"];
    }
```

asi es como se me muestra la info

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al intentar recorrelo obtengo lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podría acceder a los id de cada orden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifica esto:

```
foreach ($data as $repository){
```

por esto:

```
foreach ($data['list'] as $repository){
```

pues te estás saltando ese array **list** e intentas llegar a su contenido sin nombrarlo.

Comment: Funciono Muchas Gracias!!! :)